# Ionic - What about the real time and the database?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to code a web app which can runs on IOS, Android, Mobile browser, Desktop browser.

I tried for 6 hours Meteor but I had a lot of problems ... so I just switched to Ionic.

In 2 hours I created a simple app with a Geolocation system + Google maps and I runned it with my Iphone with Ionic View, that was a good start.

Now I need to persist my datas with a real database (please don't reply firebase) and add a real time system.

What are they the right tools and the right structure to reach that goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want firebase-like capabilities, I would recomend rethinkdb: https://www.rethinkdb.com/

Otherwise, you can try mongodb: https://www.mongodb.org/

The structure is up to you to define according to your data.